# Authentication issue while sending mail through nodemailer via service account

Tags: jwt, google-oauth, nodemailer

What I am trying to achieve is sending a mail, through nodemailer, from my web application to the recipient via a service account.

I took the reference from the following links

1. https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount
2. https://gypsyshen.com/2018/03/01/secure-gmail-access-with-oauth2-and-2lo-in-express/
3. https://nodemailer.com/smtp/oauth2/

Here is the code:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var {google} = require('googleapis');
var serviceKey = require('../key/serviceKey.json');

router.post('/', function(req, res, next){
  var jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(serviceKey.client_email, null, serviceKey.private_key, ['https://mail.google.com'], null);

  jwtClient.authorize(function(error, token){
    if(error){
      console.log('Error: ' + error);
      res.json({success: false, error: error});
      return;
    }

    console.log('JWT Authorisation Success');

    var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      host : 'smtp.gmail.com',
      port : 465,
      secure : true,
      auth : {
        type : 'OAuth2',
        user : serviceKey.client_email,
        serviceClient : serviceKey.client_id,
        privateKey : serviceKey.private_key,
        accessToken : token.access_token,
        expires : token.expiry_date
      }
    });

    var requestBody = req.body;
    var data = requestBody['data'];    

    var msg = "Data: "+data;

    transporter.sendMail({
      from: serviceKey.client_email,
      to: recipient@abc.com,
      subject : 'Test Mail',
      text : msg
    }, function(error, info){
        if(error){
          console.log("Error: "+error);
        } else {
          console.log("Success: "+info);
        }
    });


  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Now the problem which I am facing is - Although Console logs the message "JWT Authorisation Success", later when it actually sends the mail, I get this error

> Error: Invalid login: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted.
>   Learn more at 535 5.7.8 
>   https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials v5-v6sm24994162pfd.1
>   - gsmtp

I am unable to figure out the solution for this. Please help and also, suggest some good resources to know about it more.

Additional Info : The Role of the service account is set as "Service Account User"